# Migrating ACS from AppFabricLabs to production?

Tags: azure, appfabric, acs

I was using the Access Control Service for authentication AppFabric Labs but I've received an e-mail that it will be discontinued and I need to create a production account.  I've done so but I can't find where ACS is managed in the production environment.

help?

Answer (score 0):

ah... never mind.  there is a section called "Service Bus, Access Control and Caching" under "Reporting" that for some reason didn't show up before